# Debugging "client 0 refused switch" with hybrid graphics

Tags: linux, graphics, kms

I have an old MacBook with both integrated and discrete graphics, on which I run Fedora. When I first installed it, and sometimes when I update, it fails to boot with a weird "screen crash" where there is a dirty black-and-white checkerboard. People have reported issues like this many times, on many machines, over the years, and it seems the cause is trouble with the [VGA switcheroo](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/vga-switcheroo.html); dmesg will typically include a line like "vga_switcheroo: client 0 refused switch" (or "vga_switcheroo: client 1 refused switch"!).

The first time I encountered this, I found [a Red Hat bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1427340) where the best workaround was to disable (with `systemctl mask`) the alsa-switch service, which was somehow blocking the switch and leaving the system in an inconsistent state.

However, the problem came back, and disabling alsa-switch does nothing. So, presumably, there is now another program blocking the switch. How do I find out what it is?

Comment: in the bug report you link to, the command to find it using `lsof` is often mentionned, eg see comment [#46](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1427340#c46). Presumably a part of the sound is handled by the discrete GPU so the sound card musn't be in use (this includes pulseaudio etc) before switching card.

Comment: @Goro Neither *MacBook* nor *Fedora* are code so should not be formatted as such. Also, the use of present tense for *when I update, it fails* is correct as updating is something that is regularly carried out. Finally, *How can I find out* is not an improvement on *How do I find out*.

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan. thank you for the constructive comments! I Completely agree! :-)

Comment: @Goro Also, "the root is troublesome with the VGA switcheroo" is not correct - ["trouble" is a noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trouble), "troublesome" is an adjective. I've rolled back the edit - but thank you very much for caring enough to make it!

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I've uppercased the pronouns. I realise "root" might be ambiguous here; i meant "root cause", not any of the various unix-related meanings of root, so i've changed that.

Comment: @A.B I tried running that `lsof` command, but only found one process which had that socket open (pulseaudio, i think). Can that be blocking the switch? I don't really understand the VGA switcheroo stuff!

Comment: quoting myself "Presumably a part of the sound is handled by the discrete GPU so the sound card musn't be in use (this includes pulseaudio etc) before switching card". I have no proof nor understanding of that, but reading the comments in the bug report, am willing to believe. So yes that's pulseaudio. the lsof command is to look what is using **sound**, preventing **video** to work as intended. The generic solution is all in the comments.